# Use TCP socket in React Native?

Tags: websocket, react-native, javascriptcore

I want to create a TCP socket in React Native, connect to a telnet server with port of 23.

I found there has 'RCTWebSocket', but it seems only support http, https, ws, wss protocols, and always occurred error when remote response.

Is there a way to use TCP Socket which not only for http, ws protocols ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try native objective c tcp socket with a js interface.  Look for "extension " in the react native github page.

Comment: here's one with iOS and Android support. https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp

Comment: That one doesn't explain well how to use it. github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp 
Also I can't seem to use it with Native-Navigation?